# How to configure HikariCp in Springboot2.2.2release by a independent Configuration file?

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I want to use Hikaricp in springboot，and configure it by a independent Configuration file named hikari.properties
The class dataSourceConfig :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/hikari.properties")
public class dataSourceConfig {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource hikariDatasource(){
    return new HikariDataSource();
}
```

}

The hikari.properites:

```
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atcc
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.datasource.cachePrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.prepStmtCacheSize=250
spring.datasource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
spring.datasource.useServerPrepStmts=true
spring.datasource.useLocalSessionState=true
spring.datasource.rewriteBatchedStatements=true
spring.datasource.cacheResultSetMetadata=true
spring.datasource.cacheServerConfiguration=true
spring.datasource.elideSetAutoCommits=true
spring.datasource.maintainTimeStats=false
```

And the application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

When I run thin application,There had a error:

> No ConfigurationProperties annotation found on  'com.atcc.taskManager.config.dataSourceConfig'.

What's wrong with it?How to configure HikariCp  by a independent Configuration file?